# libsvm input data?

Tags: libsvm

For example I have a data set for n people like this

```
userID 1 (or 2,3.....up to n)
gender male (or female)
working yes (or No)
income >$5000/month (or <$5000)
have_car yes (or no)
```

I want to predict that a person have a car or not base on other properties (gender, working and income). What format I should use for training,and how many people should I put in training, how many for testing if let say I have data of 10,000 people

Answer (score 0):

Format: You have to use numerical data. So use could use 0 and 1 for binary decitions.

Training/Testing: There's no exact formula for that. It seems you have not a lot of features you use for classification - that means you don't necessarily need an enormous amout of trainingdata. You could split it 50:50 for the start and check if you get reasonable results.